# Comparing multiple values against multiple values

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my problem.

I have array $cities containing numeric values like this: 1,45,34,12... And I have multiple values stored in one column named 'areas' of database table 'area' like this:
2,34,24,267...

I need to compare values from 'areas' against values in array $cities (eg. 34 = 34) and get id's of each row with at least one match. So basicly I need to compare multiple values against
multiple values.

Just started with php so I don't have a clue where to start. Thanks. :)

Comment: You really should use a association table instead of an array stored in your DB.

Answer (score 0):

MYSQL has the ability to search by lists of values with a `WHERE x IN (a,b,c)` syntax.  So for your example:

```
$cities = implode(',', $cities);
$query = "SELECT id FROM table WHERE area IN ({$cities})";
```

If you run that query against the database, it should return all instance of ID where there was a match.

**EDIT**
I just saw that you are storing multiple values in a single column.  This is a bad practice and you should split out your data atomically, e.g. there should never be more than 1 value per field (look into [database normalization](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/179103-relational-database-design-normalization/)).

That being said, you're best bet may be to use an expanded REGEXP clause to perform the search.

```
$cities = implode('|', $cities);
$query = "SELECT id FROM table WHERE area REGEXP '{$cities}'";
```

Comment: Those values need escaping. You can't just slam them in there.

Comment: @tadman What I gave is a viable and workable answer.  If you noticed I left the creation of the array and the DB calls out of the answer on purpose.  My only goal was to prove a workable query to select the dataset he wants, which it does.

Comment: It's workable but without escaping completely reckless. Wherever possible, try and specify the query in terms of structure with bindings, like `REGEXP ?` instead of actually suggesting that string interpolation is the preferred method.

Comment: I agree that it should be bound and not inserted directly, but assuming the array is from non-user provided data, it's not inherently unsafe.  And given the nature of the question, I think getting into prepared statements would be a bit much for the topic at hand.  I appreciate the feedback though.

Comment: If prepared statements are "a bit much" for someone, that someone should not be writing code that interfaces with a database, they're going to do tremendous amounts of damage. Try to keep in mind that PDO takes half an hour, *at most*, to learn, as a [simple tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) demonstrates. Do not think this is some sort of insurmountable obstacle.